# Is it possible to solve this recursion relation using Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, recursion

I want to get a the recursive relation shown for $P[x,y,t]$.

$\qquad P[x,y,t]=\sum_{j=0}^{t-1} \binom{t-1}{j} ({{k_1})^{j}} ({{k_2})^{({t-1-j})}} {P[x-t+1,y-j,1]}$

I am looking for a closed form solution rather than a numeric one.

Comment: I would start by trying `RSolve`, which is specifically designed for solving recurrence equations. There's no guarantee that it will find a solution for your problem, of course, but it would be the first thing to try.

Answer (score 1):

To use `RSolve` you need something of the form

```
 p[x, y, t] == z p[x + 1, y - 1, t + 1]
```

but you have `p[x, y, t] == z p[x - t + 1, y - 1, 1]` so it will not solve.

Incidentally,

```
Sum[Binomial[t - 1, j] k1^j k2^(t - 1 - j) p[x - t + 1, y - 1, 1], {j, 0, t - 1}]
```

simplifies to

```
(k1 + k2)^(-1 + t) p[1 - t + x, -1 + y, 1]
```